# Mailcore2 IMAP Idle Operation: How to ensure the operation triggers its callback everytime a new email is received?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mailcore2

I am using Mailcore 2 windows dll provided [here](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/build-windows/README.md). I am using Visual Studio 2015 and trying to build a visual c++ console application.

Based on the discussions [here](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/301), I am using IMAPIdle operation to listen to INBOX folder on Gmail. However, it triggers the callback only one time after it is started. The connection logger has the last entry as follows:

```
9 IDLE
+ idling
```

This seems to indicate that the IDLE operation is still alive, but it never triggers the callback again when new mail arrives in INBOX. Can someone suggest how to resolve this issue? Am I missing something? Example code below:

------------ Header File -----------

```
#pragma once
#include "MailCore/Mailcore.h"
class IdleIMAPManager : public mailcore::Object, public mailcore::OperationCallback
{
public:
    mailcore::IMAPAsyncSession * idleSession;
    mailcore::IMAPIdleOperation * idleOperation;
    int lastKnownUid = 1;

    IdleIMAPManager(mailcore::IMAPAsyncSession * session, int lastKnownUid);
    ~IdleIMAPManager();
    void operationFinished(mailcore::Operation * op);
    void startIMAPInboxListener();
};
```

------------ CPP File -------------

```
#include "stdafx.h"

IdleIMAPManager::IdleIMAPManager(mailcore::IMAPAsyncSession * session, int lastKnownUid) {
    if (session != nullptr) {
        IdleIMAPManager::idleSession = session;
        IdleIMAPManager::lastKnownUid = lastKnownUid;
        IdleIMAPManager::idleOperation = IdleIMAPManager::idleSession->idleOperation(MCSTR("INBOX"), IdleIMAPManager::lastKnownUid);
        IdleIMAPManager::idleOperation->setCallback(this);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "IdleIMAPManager Error: Session is invalid\n";
    }
}


IdleIMAPManager::~IdleIMAPManager()
{
}

void IdleIMAPManager::operationFinished(mailcore::Operation * op) {
    printf("\n============ IMAP IDLE OPERATION FIRED =========\n");
}

void IdleIMAPManager::startIMAPInboxListener() {
    if (IdleIMAPManager::idleOperation == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "\nError: Inbox listener not created\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        IdleIMAPManager::idleOperation->start();
    }
}

class IdleLogger : public mailcore::ConnectionLogger {
    void log(void * sender, mailcore::ConnectionLogType logType, mailcore::Data * buffer) {
        std::string logfile = "C:\\Users\\...\\idlelog";
        std::ofstream log;
        log.open(logfile, std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
        if (log.is_open()) {
            if (buffer != nullptr) {
                log.write(buffer->bytes(), buffer->length());
            }
            log.close();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "\nLogger error: Could not open log file" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

static void win32MainLoop(void)
{
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    mailcore::AutoreleasePool * pool = new mailcore::AutoreleasePool();
    mailcore::IMAPAsyncSession * session = new mailcore::IMAPAsyncSession();
    //Create IDLE Session
    session->setHostname(MCSTR("imap.gmail.com"));
    session->setPort(993);
    session->setUsername(MCSTR("******@gmail.com"));
    session->setPassword(MCSTR("*******"));
    session->setConnectionType(mailcore::ConnectionTypeTLS);
    IdleLogger * connectionLog = new IdleLogger();
    session->setConnectionLogger(connectionLog); 

    IdleIMAPManager idler = IdleIMAPManager(session, (int)420);
    idler.startIMAPInboxListener();
    win32MainLoop();
    pool->release();
    return 0;
}
```

-------------------- Connection Logger Output ----------------

```
* OK Gimap ready for requests from xx.xx.xxx.xxx i50mb118414577qgi
1 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=XOAUTH
1 OK Thats all she wrote! i50mb118414577qgi
2 LOGIN "*******@gmail.com" "*******"
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS
2 OK **********@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
3 COMPRESS DEFLATE
3 OK Success
4 ENABLE CONDSTORE
* ENABLED CONDSTORE
4 OK Success
5 NAMESPACE
* NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL
5 OK Success
6 ID NIL
* ID ("name" "GImap" "vendor" "Google, Inc." "support-url" "http://support.google.com/mail" "version" "gmail_imap_150804.04_p0" "remote-host" "xx.xx.xxx.xxx")
6 OK Success
7 SELECT INBOX
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing \*)] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid.
* 106 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 444] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 36560]
7 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)
8 UID FETCH 420:* (UID)
* 83 FETCH (UID 420 MODSEQ (35048))
* 84 FETCH (UID 421 MODSEQ (35052))
* 85 FETCH (UID 422 MODSEQ (35055))
* 86 FETCH (UID 423 MODSEQ (35054))
* 87 FETCH (UID 424 MODSEQ (35050))
* 88 FETCH (UID 425 MODSEQ (35103))
* 89 FETCH (UID 426 MODSEQ (35147))
* 90 FETCH (UID 427 MODSEQ (35191))
* 91 FETCH (UID 428 MODSEQ (35236))
* 92 FETCH (UID 429 MODSEQ (35517))
* 93 FETCH (UID 430 MODSEQ (35797))
* 94 FETCH (UID 431 MODSEQ (35771))
* 95 FETCH (UID 432 MODSEQ (35745))
* 96 FETCH (UID 433 MODSEQ (35557))
* 97 FETCH (UID 434 MODSEQ (36078))
* 98 FETCH (UID 435 MODSEQ (36226))
* 99 FETCH (UID 436 MODSEQ (36225))
* 100 FETCH (UID 437 MODSEQ (36227))
* 101 FETCH (UID 438 MODSEQ (36550))
* 102 FETCH (UID 439 MODSEQ (36548))
* 103 FETCH (UID 440 MODSEQ (36546))
* 104 FETCH (UID 441 MODSEQ (36547))
* 105 FETCH (UID 442 MODSEQ (36549))
* 106 FETCH (UID 443 MODSEQ (36551))
8 OK Success
9 IDLE
+ idling
```